# Logging: can't find Handlers

Tags: python, file, logging, handlers

I am trying to close all the handlers at the end of my script, but for some reason logger.handlers is an empty list where the handlers should be therefore I cannot close them. Could someone explain how I can find and close my handlers?

```
import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig

logconfig = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": 0,
    "root": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "handlers": [
            "console",
            "file",
            "debugfile"
        ]
    },
    "loggers": {

    },
    "formatters": {
        "precise": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s"
        },
        "brief": {
        # Don't think we'll use. 
            "format": "%(levelname)-8s: %(name)-15s: %(message)s"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "debugfile": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "formatter": "precise",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "mode": "a",
            "filename": "debugAndUp.log"
        },
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "precise",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },
        "file": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "formatter": "precise",
            "level": "WARNING",
            "backupCount": 3,
            "maxBytes": 10240000,
            "filename": "warningAndUp.log"
        }
    }
}

dictConfig(logconfig)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug('Test')
logger.handlers >> []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just want have to remove `__name__`  `logging.getLogger(__name__)` as it refers to main and there is no handler in this name . handler is registered under default "root" handler . It will give you access.

```
import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig

logconfig = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": 0,
    "root": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "handlers": [
            "console",
            "file",
            "debugfile"
        ]
    },
    "loggers": {

    },
    "formatters": {
        "precise": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s"
        },
        "brief": {
        # Don't think we'll use. 
            "format": "%(levelname)-8s: %(name)-15s: %(message)s"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "debugfile": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "formatter": "precise",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "mode": "a",
            "filename": "debugAndUp.log"
        },
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "precise",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },
        "file": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "formatter": "precise",
            "level": "WARNING",
            "backupCount": 3,
            "maxBytes": 10240000,
            "filename": "warningAndUp.log"
        }
    }
}

logs = dictConfig(logconfig)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.debug('Test')
for handles in logger.handlers:
    print(handles.name)
    handles.close()
```

**Output -> Handlers List :**

```
console
file
debugfile
```